# How to get View if I have reference to ViewModel?

Tags: aurelia

I want to track changes of attributes of any custom element (or view). So instead of updating each view, or creating super class, I'm trying to use plugin and attach to propertyChanged observer. This way I'm in the context of VM, I have a reference to it, I have a name of changed attribute and new value. I also want a link to a view (Element). So my question is - if I have a VM how do I get a View?

To better understand I also pasting my testing code (my plugin):

```
let originalCreateObserver = BindableProperty.prototype.createObserver;

BindableProperty.prototype.createObserver = function( viewModel )
{
    let changeHandlerName = this.changeHandler;
    let name = this.name;

    let behaviorPropertyObserver: BehaviorPropertyObserver = originalCreateObserver.apply( this, arguments );
    let originalSelfSubscriber = behaviorPropertyObserver['selfSubscriber'];

    behaviorPropertyObserver['selfSubscriber'] = function()
    {
        console.log( 'attr changed', viewModel, name );
        // QUESTION: Link to a View?

        originalSelfSubscriber.apply( this, arguments );
    }

    return behaviorPropertyObserver;
}
```

Bonus question: This is quite monkey-patching. Is there a better way to attach to subscriber?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject Element into your ViewModel which give you the view.

For instance:

```
@inject(Element)
export class MyClass {
   constructor(element) {
      this.element = element;
      //do something with element;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer, because as I said "instead of updating each view, or creating super class, I'm trying to use plugin". Injecting of Element is something I would have to do for every View. I need to connect View with VM in plugin (and it's context)

Comment: Can you explain more. Which View exactly do you need to use in the plugin?

Comment: I want exactly what injected Element returns but i can't do inject, because it has to be general for each View.

Comment: Yes you have to inject it in each view and pass the reference to your plugin. Is it not possible?

Comment: It is possible, but I would like to do that automaticaly, so developers don't have to spend their time copying stuff and worry about it. It would be way better, I you just added a plugin and it worked :)